How the memory usage is calculated in function calling in Python's `tracemalloc`?
I want to ask a question regarding Python's memory usage calculation in tracemalloc. I will give an example. I have a Python code structured in this way.
def measure_performance(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        tracemalloc.start()
        start_time = perf_counter()
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
        finish_time = perf_counter()
        print("\n")
        print(f'Function: {func.__name__}')
        print(f'Memory usage:\t\t {current / 10**6:.6f} MB \n'
              f'Peak memory usage:\t {peak / 10**6:.6f} MB ')
        print(f'Time elapsed is seconds: {finish_time - start_time:.6f}')
        print(f'Run on: {datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}')
        print(f'{"-"*40}')
        tracemalloc.stop()

        return res
        
    return wrapper_func

class ClassName:
  def __init__():
    ...
  
  @measure_performance
  def A():
    ...
  
  @measure_performance
  def B():
    ...
  
  @measure_performance
  def C():
     .
     .
     .

@measure_performance
def main():
  classname = ClassName()
  a = classname.A()
  b = classname.B()
  c = classname.C()
      ...
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


On running the above code, I am getting this kind of result
Function: A
Memory usage:            191.501034 MB 
Peak memory usage:       352.158040 MB 
Time elapsed is seconds: 79.373798
Run on: 2024-12-28 00:37:05

Function: B
Memory usage:            1.591783 MB 
Peak memory usage:       14.774033 MB 
Time elapsed is seconds: 2.095723
Run on: 2024-12-28 00:37:07

Function: C
Memory usage:            2.196528 MB 
Peak memory usage:       750.238682 MB 
Time elapsed is seconds: 190.336022
Run on: 2024-12-28 00:40:18

Function: main
Memory usage:            0.000000 MB 
Peak memory usage:       0.000000 MB 
Time elapsed is seconds: 272.908980
Run on: 2024-12-28 00:40:18

My question is that for each function we are getting some memory usage and peak memory usage, but for the main we are getting 0.0 memory usage and peak memory usage. Why is that, even though we call ClassName in main? Is this normal behavior or how is this working?
